# Refreshing page takes me to first view

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my angular [project](https://github.com/sriramsridhar26/airtel-frontend)

If I refresh from a view, it takes me to login page. Can anyone tell me what am I missing out or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the purpose of `
                history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);  
                this.location.onPopState(() => {
                history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);` what are you trying to achieve??

Comment: UsI'm absolutely no angular expert but I believe you'd want to use a *guard* to protect the views that require to be logged in. As described by user1075296 you seem to just force navigation to the login page on load which causes the effect you describe.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it is due to your line in your constructor in your app.component.ts :

```
this.router.navigate(['components', 'login']);
```

Each time you refresh your app, it will navigate to the login page.